# Table Data Structure Design

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html-table

I am trying to create a data structure to hold a dynamic table in React. Currently, I'm holding my data as

```
[
   {item00: "data 0", item01: "data 1", item02: "data 2"},
   {item10: "data 3", item11: "data 4", item12: "data 5"},
   {item20: "data 6", item21: "data 7", item22: "data 8"}
]
```

and adding a new row would mean appending a

```
{item30: "data 9", item31: "data 10", item32: "data 11"}
```

and adding a new column would mean inserting `item03`, `item13`, `item23` and `item33` at the end of each row.

My question is, is there any better data structure I could use? I'm having trouble with coming up with something that would make inserting new columns easy.

Also, how would I keep a counter of the columns I am adding / deleting? I'm sure there are specific ways of doing that, but I'm having trouble coming up with appropriate search terms..

Comment: Can you tell us more about the bigger goal you are trying to achieve?  This feels like an XY problem, but hard to say.  Are you using Flux or Redux?

Comment: I just want to be able to dynamically increase the size of a table containing data. My data is literally a table though, with rows representing options and columns representing criteria. I'm going to display the table with whatever data exists right now, and allow the user to press an add column/add row button.
I'm super new to this web app thing, I'm not sure I am using either? I'm using React on top of Meteor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can consider this,

Make each element inside the `Array` as a row.

Example:

```
[{}, {}, {}, {}] //each {} is a row
```

Make each element inside the `Object` as a column,

Example:

```
[
  {name: "xyz", age: "21", location: "india"}, //this will be a row
  //name, age, location will be columns
]
```

New row can be appended inside the `Array` with the same or additional columns.

Example:

Original Data

var t = [
      {name: "xyz", age: "21", location: "india"}, 
    ]

Adding new Data

```
t.push({name: 'abc', age: '44', location: 'india', phone: 56654345})
```

Rendered table will be

```
Name     Age     Location   Phone
--------------------------------------
xyz    | 21   |  india    |   
abc    | 44   |  india    |  56654345
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was doing. I guess this is what does make the most sense and there's no better way to do it..